# I have modified one dotnetnuke website and uploaded it on new server (Host-gator) from my local development server it gives me the error

Tags: dotnetnuke

When I am trying to access site in browser it gives me following error:

> 'Framework' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

```
Private Shared Sub CreateProvider()
    ' [alex - 09/01/09] removed  object assembly name (required for WPA projects)
    objProvider = CType(Framework.Reflection.CreateObject("data", "DotNetNuke.Modules.Links", ""), DataProvider)
End Sub
```

> Source File: D:\InetPub\vhosts\coolsimsoftware.com\httpdocs\App_Code\Links\DataProvider.vb    Line: 53

How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: Which .net framework are you using and did you set website in local IIS?

Comment: @Dexterity I am using .net framework 4.0 and i setup website locally it works fine